# Two NGINX servers one passing CORS issue

Tags: nginx, cors

I have two nginx servers running on my localhost through docker. I want one server to call to the other one (api) through ajax and react. I got all of this working at one point, but I fired up my servers again and I am getting:

> Failed to load http://localhost:8081/items?Title=butterflies: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

So the Cors issue has returned. I have the following code in my default.conf:

```
server {
    listen  8080;

    root    /app/public;
    index   index.php index.html;
    charset utf-8;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    error_page 404 = /handle404.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*" always;
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "POST, GET, OPTIONS" always;
    }

    # Docker image version endpoints
    location /version {
        default_type text/plain;
        rewrite ^/version/bisapi-php$ /version/bisapi-php.php last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 900;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
```

Also, here is my code where I call the api in react:

```
var encodedURI = window.encodeURI('http://localhost:8081/items?Title=butterflies', { crossdomain: true });
    return axios.get(encodedURI).then(function(response){
        return response.data;
    });
```

So I clearly have a universal call within my root for my site. Not sure why it won't allow this. I am sort of in newb territory with nginx, so please help.

Comment: You need to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Methods headers on the 8081 server. They’re not necessary on the 8080 server, because that’s where your frontend code’s running. So instead the server your frontend code is sending the cross-origin request to needs to return those headers in its response.

Comment: Yes, that is the server that currently is running my default.conf with the code above, which includes Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Methods. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I took my headers out of the location \ and put them inside the server tag to globally call the header and it worked. I must have been on a different path.